# How to do XSS in HackerOne level 0 website

Tags: xss

*Screenshot:*
[image: ScreenShot]
[image: Website Source code]

I try to do reflected XSS attack but since the POST form isn't running the script. Instead, it is just regurgitating whatever is to the right of the equal sign. How should I do reflected XSS here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some things you can try. It is putting your XSS payload as the value of the input box.

Occasionally a payload such as the following will be able to 'escape' the input box so to speak, and then be treated as much more than a simple value:

```
"><script>alert('XSS!');</script>
```

Note that the `">` is going to close off the value and then the input box will be closed too. Once your code is outside of the input box, it is embedded within the site and then executed.

If the site protects from this, it may not be vulnerable to XSS, at least not in this exact point of entry. I've seen many sites which do protect from the above payload, but also a lot which don't.